# Tensor Product simple tensor

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I,J \unlhd R$. Then I can consider the tensor product $R/I \otimes_{R} R/J$, where $R/I, R/J$ are R-modules. Then how do I show that every element in this tensor product is of the form $ 1 \otimes r$. I was thinking let $r \otimes s \in R/I \otimes_{R} R/J$. Then $r \otimes s = r \cdot 1 \otimes s = 1 \otimes rs$. Is this right? Also, how do I show that $\phi: R/I \otimes_{R} R/J \rightarrow R(I+J)$, $(a,b) \mapsto (ab)$ has kernel $\{0\}$?

Comment: In general showing something is 0 in a tensor product is hard. Once you show that everything is of the form $1 \otimes r$ this will be easier, but you could also just define a left inverse to your map. This is often easier.

Comment: The manipulation in $r \otimes s = r\cdot 1 \otimes s = 1 \otimes rs$ is indeed correct. That's because you are taking the tensor product over $R$, so you have a compatibility between the actions and, since $R$ is commutative, you are using the standard $R$-module structure on both $R/I$ and $R/J$. It's important to understand what is going on with the tensor product. Moreover, as @paulblartmathcop said, you should look for the inverse of $\phi$, it's easier. Use the fact that elements of your tensor product have the form $1 \otimes r$ to define your inverse mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You also have to consider what happens to an element like $a \otimes b + c \otimes d$. For the second half it suffices to consider what happens to an element of the form $1 \otimes a$, which is sent to $a$.